# Setting AspNetUserRoles when Registering users

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, registration, account, role

Here's what I want to do: I want to set the **AspNetUserRole** to the new user, right in the Registration page.

**Model:**

```
    namespace MyProject.Models
    {
        public enum AccountRole
        {
            Responder = 10003, Sender= 10002, Admin = 10001
        }

        ...

        [Required()]
        [Display(Name = "Account role")]
        public AccountRole? AccountRole { get; set; }
```

**View:**

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.AccountRole, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.AccountRole, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AccountRole, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
```

**Registration page result:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEokn.jpg

**Controller:**

```
    // POST: /Account/Register
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                //User accountRole to AspNetUserRoles BY JULIUS
                var accountRole = model.AccountRole;

                await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);

                string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account",
                   new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id,
                   "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\""
                   + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");


                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                AddErrors(result);
            }
        }
```

Please direct your attention to the **AccountController.cs** Register part.
I have successfully collected the entered the **AccountRole Enum** from the dropdown:

```
var accountRole = model.AccountRole;
```

What I want to do is set `accountRole` to the **AspNetUserRoles** table in my Entity Framework generated **DefaultConnection**

**Table:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMEQ2.png

How do I solve this in my Controller code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I understand you may want to extend the `IdentityUserRole` class.
This class represents the relation between a user and his role.

```
public class AccountRole: IdentityUserRole<TKey>
{
    public override TKey RoleId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public override TKey UserId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public IdentityUserRole()
    {
    }

    public string somenewproperty(){
        get; set;
    }
}
```

Then I believe you will have to override your `createUserRole` in the `userManager` or more specific the `RoleManager`

```
public class ApplicationRoleManager : RoleManager<IdentityRole> {
 //...And so on
}
```

[Check out this link for a full overview of the identity management](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/790720/ASP-NET-Identity-Customizing-Users-and-Roles)

What I don't really get is why you would want to do this in the first place.
You could add a new role to the `Roles` table and tie that role to certain rules and in that case you could just use the built-in `RoleManager` to assign roles to users.

`await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(userId, AccountRole.Admin);`

and in this case, your `AccountRole` will be an `Enum`

```
public enum AccountRole {
    Admin,
    User
}
```

So to make this work, you will have to add the roles to the database like so:

```
 context.Roles.Add(new IdentityRole("SomeRoleNameHere"));
```

this is best done in the Seed method;

Then you have your register method:

```
[Route("Register")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(RegisterBindingModel model)
{
    //Do the register of the user
    //Next:
    await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(userId, AccountRole.Admin);
}
```

This will add the user to the role of "Admin" if added correctly.
Now if you look in the database, the AspNetUserRoles will have your UserId and RoleId matched to one another.

If you cannot get this to work, you can also make a static class, I did this in a previous project.
It works the same way only the "rolenames" object looks like this:

```
public static class RoleNames {
    public const string Supervisor = "Supervisor";
    public const string Administrator = "Administrator";
}
```

All the other things - like adding them to the DB in the seed method and so on are exactly the same.
And adding it to a user as well:

```
await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(UserId, RoleNames.Supervisor);
```

Comment: Geez, that is a big headache. Maybe my way would work also? The fact is that when i manually input the data into the table, it works just fine. So maybe there can be a work around in this situation?

Comment: So there is built in functionality?

Comment: To add roles to a user, yes! Why would you want to assign a string to a role? What is the purpose of it? You can just define your role as an enum (see above) and use this to assign the role. In your seed method of the database, you add the roles to the database so you can use this enum. `context.Roles.Add(new IdentityRole(roleName));`

Comment: The Roles are in the enum. The value ("10001") -is the value beeing inputed to database table shown in the second image.

The pupose is to assign a Role to a Account when Registering it, simply.

I have the value ready to be input to the database table. I feel that I am very close to solving the problem.

I will try your latest suggestion

Comment: The value has a reason? Because in the Identity 2.0 it is put as a string with a GUID as Id. So I don't see the "businessvalue" of the value on a role...

Comment: I'm sorry if I am beeing difficult to teach this thing. But I do not get it:

I do not have a `IdentityUserRole` class in my project. Nor a `ApplicationRoleManager`.

Even my Register method looks different to yours (not changed since creating project).

Comment: `IdentityUserRole` and `ApplicationRoleManager` are both part of the Identity framework of microsoft, which you are using. So it should be available for you. Maybe have a look at the documentation of `Identity 2.0`.